How to create a script that copies and renames a file to a certain folder?
I'll explain the scenario better: I set up a karaoke "system" with a frontend called Attract Mode, in Linux Mint 22, where the videos are played by VLC. The command line that plays the video looks like this: --aspect-ratio=16:9 --no-video-title-show --play-and-exit --fullscreen "[romfilename]" /home/pc/KARAOKE/NOTA/nota.mp4, where "[romfilename]" is the file to be played and the second video is the note displayed at the end of the first video playback.
The target of this script is the second video, which will vary with each execution. At first, I thought that each time this script ran the loop, it would modify the Nota.mp4 file with another one that would have a different "note" for the singers.
Despite using Linux, I don't have much knowledge of shell scripting.
I tried to create this .sh but as there are several files in the base, I didn't understand how to make it run in a loop.

Please read the How-to-ask and  On-topic  sections in the [help]. Good luck.

Put the videos you want to play in a folder, then just loop through them
#!/bin/bash

# Directory containing the karaoke videos and note videos
KARAOKE_DIR=/home/pc/KARAOKE/VIDEOS
NOTE_DIR=/home/pc/KARAOKE/NOTES

# List all the karaoke video files (you can adjust the pattern to match your files)
KARAOKE_VIDEOS=($KARAOKE_DIR/*.mp4)

# Loop through all karaoke videos
for karaoke_video in "${KARAOKE_VIDEOS[@]}"; do
    vlc --aspect-ratio=16:9 --no-video-title-show --play-and-exit --fullscreen "$karaoke_video"
    NOTE_VIDEO="$NOTE_DIR/nota.mp4"
    vlc --aspect-ratio=16:9 --no-video-title-show --play-and-exit --fullscreen "$NOTE_VIDEO"
done



if you needed to quote rhs of KARAOKE_DIR definition then you need to quote every usage too (eg. rhs of KARAOKE_VIDEOS definition)

Yeah, its my weird habbit. Will remove quote from definitions, but I think it doesn't make much of a difference.

generally, it's safer to quote variable use unless there is a specific reason not to - consider when someone replaces your (now-unquoted) KARAOKE_DIR rhs with a quoted path containing spaces

That will be another question on stackoverflow. Some easy extra reputation for us.

When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?

Also don't use upper case for your private variables and probably don't assign the same value to the note video file inside the loop (in fact, why use a variable at all if the value is constant?)
